# How to list component fields in a class

Tags: java

If I give you a class like:

```
public class A {
        protected ClassType a1;
        protected ClassType a2;
        protected int a3;
    }
    public class B {
        protected ClassType b1;
        protected EnumType b2;
        protected boolean b3;
    }
    public enum C {
        c1,
        c2,
        c3
    }
    public class All {
        protected ClassType A;
        protected ClassType B;
        protected EnumType C;
    }
```

How can I write a function through which class object "**All**" is passed,,,like "`foo(All all);`" to get **all the members' names(like "A") in "all"** including **its member's member's name**?

I don't know if I made that clear.

Thanks in advance !
**:-)**

Comment: No idea what you're asking. Is this a reflection-related question?

Comment: Ditto, I've no idea what you're trying to do. Try to give more details on what you're trying to achieve and not the code you're using to try to achieve it.

Comment: You want a method to list all of the variables of a class and if those variables are non-primitive types, to list all of their variables as well?

Comment: @Carth Thanks.Yeah,that's what i wanna say.Do you have some solutions or ideas?

Comment: @Zhao already posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an instance of all. Just the class object. [Use the getDeclaredFields method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)